# How would you differentiate a dismiss icon from a delete icon?

Tags: icon

I currently have two icons I am using for list items in an application. Accept, represented by a check mark, and reject, represented by and X mark. I need to add a third icon for dismiss. Dismiss or cancel are commonly represented by and X mark as well. The context of the app and colors make it clear what the first two buttons do. Any ideas for the dismiss button?

Answer (score 4):

I have worked with similar sets that included Delete, Cancel and Dismiss, but in my case the Dismiss button was rather an Undo action ("Dismiss all changes").

***Undo*** is much easier to represent, so if this is the sort of thing you would expect the button to do, you could go with something like:

[image]

Now, if your dismiss goes more in the direction of "***Ignore*** and open next" or similar, perhaps you could perhaps use something that shows the act of moving to a different element for the icon:

[image]

In any case, I would try not to think about the action itself, but about the sort of *effect* it produces instead.

Alternatively, you can use the X for dismiss, and use something else for **Delete**, like a in:

[image]

Whatever you choose, make sure you reinforce the action with some **text** or a **tooltip** explaining what each one does.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. My dismiss icon just removes the item from an alert list. The user stays on the list and the item is not really deleted except from display on this list.

Comment: @rdellara Maybe a "minus" symbol? Since a cross could be easily confused for a delete button. A minus makes sense in a list.

Comment: This was what I came up with, but it just doesn't look right. I am in the process of trying a thumbs up, thumbs down for accept and reject and using the x for dismiss.